# Solve issue with a solution at zero

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to understand why `Solve` overcounts a solution at zero, or undercounts it altogether in different cases:

For example, the input

```
Solve[x^2 == 0, x]
Solve[x^2 (1 - x) == 0, x]
Solve[x^2 (1 - x) (1 - r x) == 0, x]
Solve[x^2 (1 - x) (1 - r/x) == 0, x]
Solve[x^2 (1 - x) (1 - r/x)^2 == 0, x]
```

returns

```
{{x->0},{x->0}}

{{x->0},{x->0},{x->1}}

{{x->0},{x->0},{x->1},{x->1/r}}

{{x->0},{x->1},{x->r}}

{{x->1},{x->r},{x->r}}
```

The solution of `x->0` behaves in a way I don't understand.
Thanks.

Comment: consider what happens when solving eg $(x-2)^2=0$; how many solutions do you get? (perhaps check [*Multiplicity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)) too)

Comment: As noted by others in slightly different terms, `x` is not an actual factor of the left hand side. 'In[115]:= Factor[x^2 (1 - x) (1 - r/x)^2]

Out[115]= -(r - x)^2 (-1 + x)'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.

Comment: Thanks very much, my bad

Answer (score 1):

{x->0} is not a solution for the last equaiton since it contains $1/x^{2}$ which is later multiplied by $x^2$. Previous has {x->0} because it has $1/x$ which is multiplied by $x^2$.
The output you get is perfectly fine, try `Expand[]` function on each of your input.

Comment: `Simplify` will also eliminate the removable singularities